# Get value of item when it first and last appears

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
Item    Date    Count
Item_1  01/06/2023  25
Item_1  02/06/2023  14
Item_1  03/06/2023  5
Item_1  04/06/2023  7
Item_2  03/06/2023  41
Item_2  04/06/2023  49
Item_2  05/06/2023  2
Item_2  06/06/2023  38
```

and would like to aggregate to a new df with a line per item to show

```
1 - when it first appeared
2 - the value of "Count" when it first appeared 
3 - when it last appeared 
4 - the value of "Count" when it last appeared 
5 - the minimum value of "Count" per item
6 - the maximum value of "Count" per item
```

So it should look like

```
Item    Earliest_date   Count_at_earliest_date  Latest_date Count_at_latest_date    Min_of_count    Max_of_count
Item_1  01/06/2023  25  04/06/2023  25  5   25
Item_2  03/06/2023  41  06/06/2023  41  2   49
```

I can get 1, 3, 5, 6 with

```
df2 = df.groupby('Item').agg(earliest_date =('Date', 'min'), latest_date =('Date', 'max'), min_count = ('Count', 'min'), max_count = ('Count', 'max'))
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

But I can't figure how to get 2 and 4.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort your dataframe by dates first and use `first` and `last` to get -2- and -4-:

```
df2 = (df.sort_values('Date').groupby('Item', as_index=False)
         .agg(earliest_date =('Date', 'min'),
              count_at_earliest_date=('Count', 'first'),
              latest_date =('Date', 'max'),
              count_at_latest_date=('Count', 'last'),
              min_count = ('Count', 'min'),
              max_count = ('Count', 'max')))
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
     Item earliest_date  count_at_earliest_date latest_date  count_at_latest_date  min_count  max_count
0  Item_1    01/06/2023                      25  04/06/2023                     7          5         25
1  Item_2    03/06/2023                      41  06/06/2023                    38          2         49
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's first create a df:
import pandas as pd

```
# Let's first create a df
data = {
    'Item': ['Item_1', 'Item_1', 'Item_1', 'Item_1', 'Item_2', 'Item_2', 'Item_2', 'Item_2'],
    'Date': ['01/06/2023', '02/06/2023', '03/06/2023', '04/06/2023', '03/06/2023', '04/06/2023', '05/06/2023', '06/06/2023'],
    'Count': [25, 14, 5, 7, 41, 49, 2, 38]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Then applying the main logic

```
# change date format first
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# sort based on Datew
df = df.sort_values('Date')

# group based on Items
df_first = df.groupby('Item').first().reset_index()
df_last = df.groupby('Item').last().reset_index()

# Rename columns
df_first = df_first.rename(columns={'Date': 'Earliest_date', 'Count': 'Count_at_earliest_date'})
df_last = df_last.rename(columns={'Date': 'Latest_date', 'Count': 'Count_at_latest_date'})

# get min and mac
df_min_max = df.groupby('Item').agg(Min_of_count=('Count', 'min'), Max_of_count=('Count', 'max')).reset_index()

# and merge them at last
df_result = pd.merge(df_first, df_last, on='Item')
df_result = pd.merge(df_result, df_min_max, on='Item')

df_result
```